# Caching per-app in Django rather than per-site or per-view

Tags: python, django, django-middleware, django-cache, django-caching

Lets say I have two apps in my Django website one for the API and one for the html pages, all urls starting with /api/ are handled by the API app. I have setup two caches with a specific setup for each like so:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'page_cache',
        'TIMEOUT': 7200,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES': 300,
        }
    },
    'api': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'api_cache',
        'TIMEOUT': 3600,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES': 3000,
        }
    }
}
```

How would I setup so that all requests to the API use the 'api' cache and all other requests use the 'default' cache?

I know I can use the cache_page function/decorator in the 'api' apps urls or views but I have a lot of urls and views so this would be annoying to maintain if I wanted to alter the timeout for instance.

I am also aware that I could just customise the middleware to point to a different cache when the request starts with '/api/' but is there no cleaner way of doing this?